# Android smartphone with SD and FM

Tags: android, smartphones

I was all set to buy the One Plus 5 but realised that it doesn't support SD cards or have an FM radio. I looked at the Xiaomi Mi6 as well but that's similarly hobbled.

Can anyone recommend a decent spec Android Nougat smartphone, 5" display or bigger with SD card support and an active FM chip please?

Budget, as it's been asked below, is up to what those two phones would cost in the EU (€450-550)

Comment: Do you have a specific budget in mind?

Comment: No, but not averse to spending the money that either of the two phones above cost, which in the EU, cost €450-550

Comment: The phones in the answer below surpass the OnePlus 5 in performance and other phone swag, and cost a lot less than €550, they are £200 in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as your budget supports it, I would recommend the Motorola Moto G5 or the G5 Plus. If you are looking even better that that, the the Motorola Moto Z is pretty good.

The reason why I suggest Motorola is because they have NO bloatware and they are fast, very fast. Most of them come standard with multiple gbs of RAM, top end processors etc.

They are also very good value for money. For buying, just Google the make and model, and put "sim free" at the end, unless you intend to buy from the high street.

If these options don't suit you, I would suggest using www.gsmarena.com and specify what you want in their advanced search.

Comment: There is a whole lotta phones out there that fit your needs, Motorola just rule basically.

Comment: Thanks ever so much - I've had a cursory look at them and will weigh up. The Z is an older phone with a lesser battery and greater resolution - would that be likely to be an issue in daily usage?

Comment: Depends really what you are using it for. How many hours a day do you actually use it?

Comment: Usage depends, calls, texting, WhatsApps, podcasts, photos, streaming music and video.

Comment: Just looking at the Z2 on gsmarena I note that they've dropped the FM radio AND increased the price to an estimated €700! :-S

Comment: Ouch. Thats a bit expensive. There is always the LG G5. Also, for your usage, as long as you dont use it extensively, it should be fine. My phone is over 5 years old now and I still only use 8% of the battery for a day of light usage. Its all down to battery hogging apps like wifi always on.